# When click print from 1 to 10, on the second click print from 10 to 20 etc

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a button where the user can click and that what will happen:

```
var score = 0;
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', addScore);
function addScore() {
    score += 5;
}
```

And now it's the step that I don't know how to make:

When the user click the button the function addScore should work, after this function worked, there is something need to be printed on the screen:

and it must be for the first click:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

on the secound click the printed text must be

```
6
7
8
9
10
etc
```

Comment: first of all you are not printing anything to screen in your code, you should create some html element and then update it on each click. Second thing is that you add 5 to score and you will get results like 5 10 15 20 etc not 12356 etc. There is great tutorials about javascript on youtube by netninja and you can also visit Freecodecamp.org

Comment: Use a for loop. Format a string with the results. Then show it

Answer (score 1):

You can add a loop and, with a bit of math, calculate the range of numbers that you need to add with each click.

```js
var clicked = 0;

const div = document.querySelector('div');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', addScore);

function addScore() {

  // Get the new range
  // e.g initially this will be 1 (5 * 0) + 1
  const range = (5 * clicked) + 1;

  // Set up a new array to which we will add the numbers
  let arr = [];

  // Loop from range to range + 5 and push each
  // number into the array
  for (let i = range; i < range + 5; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
  }

  // Join the array with a `<br/>` element and add it to before the
  // end of your output div
  div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `${arr.join('<br/>')}<br/>`);

  // Increase the click value
  ++clicked;
}
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
var score = 0;
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', addScore);
function addScore() {
    var html = '';
    for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
        html+=(score+1)+'<br>';
        score++;
    }
    document.getElementById('#idofcontentdiv').innerHTML = html;
}
```

This increments score upto next 5 iterations and keeps its value into a variable 'html', then use the variable to put into a dom element content.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: i got working example here is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/apd0z7ho/

html

```
var score = 0;
<button id="button">click me</button>
<p id="results"></p>
```

javascript

```
var score = 0;
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', addScore);
function addScore() {
    score += 5;
    for(var i = score-5; i < score; i++){
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += i+1+"<br>";
     }
}
```

Comment: If score = 0, initially, it will show -5, -4, -3, -2, -1

Comment: you need to add 5 into score before this will happen i make fiddle for you W8

Answer (score -1):

Add following inside addScore() method :

```
function addScore(){
  for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    console.log(++score)
}
```

Variable score should be initialized to 0

Since you have not specified where exactly to print, I am assuming it is console.